# Как пресечь стили сторонних браузерных плагинов

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, плагин

Используя на очередном проекте бутстрап столкнулся с тем, что плагин для хрома, который встраивает в страницу какой-то чат у клиента добавляет в разметку свои стили, которые пересекаются с бутстрап стилями и само собой ломают их.
Есть ли возможность застраховаться от подобных горе плагинов, стили которых не достаточно "изолированы"? Может есть какие-нибудь js плагины, которые не позволяют сторонним плагинам вставлять свои стили?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться свойством стилей [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all). Правда это свойство не поддерживается Сафари и ИЕ.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как это св-во мне поможет.

Comment: Вы прочитали документацию по ссылке? Там есть даже примеры. Что вы не поняли?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не сразу понял что именно это св-во делает. Но используя его на данном этапе, а именно прелонч я очень рискую где-то что-то поломать. 
Всё равно спасибо за совет.

Comment: @UFleming это свойством можно использовать в "области", так что при правильном использовании вряд ли вы что то поломаете.